# Fedora remix not working with rca cable

Tags: operating-systems, setup, display

When I use Raspbian I can start my Raspberry Pi with my analogue TV connected over a RCA cable. After I installed Fedora remix I don't get anything on screen.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Q&A. Please try and use proper grammar (like capitals, punctuation and sensible sentence structure) when asking questions. Generally you should only ask one specific question as open ended question can lead to unwanted discussions. Please read the [FAQ](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: You are not plugging it into your antenna input, are you?

Comment: i guess the wiring is correct because it works with Raspbian weezy, only fedora remix doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect either the config.txt file or the version of the firmware for the Broadcom chip used in Fedora are causing problems. Make a backup of everything in the FAT32 boot section of the Fedora SD card, and then copy everything EXCEPT kernel.img and cmdline.txt from the Rasbian boot section to the Fedora one, overwriting files as necessary (that's why there's a backup!). Hopefully this would fix the problem.